# WP8 C# Website Scraping with Login

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, web-scraping

I'm working on a project of a mobile version of an archaic Online Learning System in my campus. I've been trying for weeks to scrape something in this website, but I need to login first in order to get it. I have search anything including `HttpWebRequest, CookiesAwareWebClient, etc`

My method until now is:

1. Find the "action" URL in the login form of the site
2. Sent POST request to that URL
3. Receive response containing cookies in the `Headers["Set-Cookie"]`
4. Create new `HttpWebRequest` with the URL to the content(that need to be logged in first).
5. Copy the headers of set-cookie into that request.
6. Run it (but fails)

I also have tried using `CookieCollection` in `CookieAwareWebClient` but it didn't work too.

How to do it properly? Is the location of a Cookie in HttpWebRequest is only in Headers, or in HTTP Packets, where is the location of CookieCollection? Does CookieCollection included in the next request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will process and hold the cookies for you between `HttpWebRequest` objects:

```
var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

var loginWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(loginUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
loginWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
// Execute the Web Request

var authRequiredWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(protectedUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
authRequiredWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
// Execute the next request
// It will have the auth cookie set appropriately
```

Comment: do I execute the web request like this?

`loginWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), loginWebRequest);`

it will run the ResponseCallback() function, do I need to run 
`var authRequiredWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(protectedUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
authRequiredWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;`
inside the ResponseCallback() function? If yes, what about the cookieJar?

Comment: @JohanesEffendi - You can execute the request however you want but you are correct that you need to wait until the first request executes before executing the second. You also don't need to do anything with `cookieJar` as the HttpWebRequest will update it for you.